# How to download 64 bit Visual Studio Code?

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, visual-studio-code

**Background**

Whenever I try to install Visual Studio Code (basic or insiders edition), I download the setup file called something like `VSCodeSetup`. This seems to install the 32 bit version. When I download the zip file, I also end up with the a 32 bit version. I've tried downloading it with both Edge and Chrome, which are both 64 bit. There appears to be 64 bit versions for Linux, so I'm assuming there are 64 bit versions for Windows as well?

**Question**

1. Is there a 64 bit version of Visual Studio Code?
2. If there is, how can it be downloaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now you have visual studio code x64 stable build. Go here - [Official download](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The [Running VS Code on Windows web page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows) emphasizes the following:

> By default, VS Code is installed under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code for a 64-bit machine.

In other words, there doesn't seem to be a native 64-bit version of Visual Studio Code.

Comment: There is an open issue in Git asking for a 64-bit version for Windows: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/507

Comment: The Insiders build is now available for 64-bit Windows (https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders). 64-bit support is reportedly coming to Stable in July.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 64 bit version. All versions, on all platforms are 32-bit only.

And it doesn't really matter for an editor environment. Having a 64-bit version in stead of a 32-bit version doesn't give you any noticeable benefit.
The 32-bit version works fine on a 64-bit OS.
So it makes sense Microsoft only makes the 32-bit version (which they need to make anyway for 32-bit systems) and don't bother with a 64-bit version that they will have to test and deploy separately.
A 64-bit just isn't needed and requires extra effort.
(This is in fact the case for many applications, from many vendors.)

Comment: RE "64-bit just isn't needed": Some extensions, e.g. the OmniSharp C# one, seem to require a 64-bit version of VSCode. More exactly, this extension says it requires 64-bit _Windows_ for for the C# debugger. Running 32-bit VSCode on 64-bit Windows still seems to trigger a complaint from this extension about the debugger not loading.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt Obviously you need 64-bit Windows to run the 64-bit debugger and you can't load the 64-bit debugger from a 32-bit application like VSCode. I'm not familiar with OmniSharp, but wouldn't  this plugin be able to  talk to the debugger if the debugger was launched separately in stead of via VSCode?

Comment: Digging in to this a bit more, it seems that VSCode C# support is really mean to be used with .NET Core, so it may be that 32-bit/64-bit versions of VSCode aren't the root of my problems: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/csharp.

AFAIK .Net Core is more commonly used on Linux where the 64-bit version of VSCode +is+ available. At this point we're getting off-topic though.

Comment: @CharlieJoynt Just checked my iMac. VScode is 64 bit there as well. In fact it is 64-bit only. No 32 bit binary or dual-architecture. Rather funny to see Microsoft doing better on non-Windows platforms :-)